# Node.js encodings enums

Tags: node.js, enums

Does Node.js contain the enum for supporting encodings, just like there is constants enum for HTTP-status codes, e.g.: `httpConstants.HTTP_STATUS_OK` inside of `http2` package?

An option to hardcode an encoding in a code, something like that:

```js
const ENCODING_OUT = "base64";
```

doesn't look so pleasant.

Comment: What enums? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @VLAZ, something like [enums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type), I prefer to avoid hard-coding the constant text values to avoid possible typo errors. In context of Node.js, some system constant have such enums, e.g.: `httpConstants.HTTP_STATUS_OK`.

Comment: `httpConstants` is not an enum, it's an object defined by that library (a.k.a. "hard-coded"). You can define your own objects, but that would hardly be different to what you already have `const encodings = {base64: "base64"};`.

Comment: ...that is to say: it's highly unlikely that node comes with a pre-defined, universal, definitive list of encodings.

Comment: @Tomalak there is actually a predefined list documented here [Buffers and character encodings](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings).

Comment: @MickaelB. Yes, in the docs - I was referring to a pre-defined list *in code*, i.e. as part of node's API, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such enum, but you can make one from the list provided in the `Buffer` documentation [Buffers and character encodings](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings).

You can see in the [source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/6140b3753fd6160b0c50a61500c04de8e36f9c05/lib/buffer.js#L586) how they define the encodings but the object is not exported.

You could write your enum like:

```js
export const ENCODINGS = {
    // Character encodings
    utf8 = 'utf8',
    utf16le = 'utf16le',
    latin1 = 'latin1',
    // Binary-to-text encodings
    base64 = 'base64',
    base64url = 'base64url', // new since v15.7.0
    hex = 'hex',
    // Legacy character encodings
    ascii = 'ascii',
    binary = 'binary',
    ucs2 = 'ucs2'
}
```

Note that they might update that list in new versions to add or remove values and you might need to update your enum accordingly with new versions.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I assumed. Just wanted to verify that I don't reinvent a wheel. That's pity, that Node.js doesn't have a well-formed publicly available entity with pre-defined system constants.